# spring caching at server startup

Tags: java, spring-boot

I am using spring method level annotations @cacheable to cache the data that I fetched from database.
Can I perform caching with the above annotation at server Start up?
I tried this but it is again fetching  from database not from cache.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add a [@PostConstruct](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html) annotation to your methods that you want to cache on server start up.

If your beans are on singleton scope, return values of methods would be cached before your application starts.

You can do this manually however, above is a very simple straightforward approach.

Comment: Be aware too many PostConstruct can delay your server start up, You may want to learn @Async as well to decide if you need on start up caching or can do async way

Answer (score 0):

No. At least one request has to be made before you cache response data. That first request could either be by application user or by code itself in Post Construct as mentioned by @Pumpkin